# Apply inner-shadow to UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilabel, shadow

I want to apply inner-shadow to a UILabel. I have a solution, but it's not good enough. Anyone with a better solution?

```
// UILabel subclass

- (void) drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGSize myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
    float myColorValues[] = {255, 0, 0, 1};

    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(myContext);

    CGColorSpaceRef myColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGColorRef myColor = CGColorCreate(myColorSpace, myColorValues);

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor (myContext, myShadowOffset, 5, myColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(myContext, kCGBlendModeLighten);

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGColorRelease(myColor);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorSpace); 

    CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);
}
```

I'm familiar with the layer property of UILabel, but `shadow offset` gives us a outer-shadow, NOT inner-shadow (unless i'm missing something).

Comment: Have you tried negative values in myShadowOffset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to do this but finally opted to use the default `shadowOffset` and play with the `shadowColor` to give the inner drop shadow effect to the text. In small texts it gives you a good inner shadow effect. For example, if you have a grayColor background and apply a whiteColor to the shadow, then you have an acceptable inner shadow effect.

Sometimes, it's better to design those texts with graphic tools and make localized copies if needed.

Answer (score 24):

Borrowing on Ruben's answer above, if you do the reverse ie. set your text color equal to your background color (with low alpha) and then set the shadow to be a stronger color, it creates a decent inset effect. Here's what I mean (Note: My view background is white):

```
cell.textLabel.textColor     = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
cell.textLabel.shadowColor   = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
cell.textLabel.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(-1.0,-1.0);
[cell.textLabel setText:@"Welcome to MyApp!"];
```

and this is the output

[image: inset UILabel text]

This would probably only work on very light backgrounds as I suspect it will create unwanted overlay on darker backgrounds.

You can ofcourse vary the shadowOffset to change the direction of light.

Comment: Very simple, a great solution.

Answer (score 3):

Answer here : [Inner Shadow in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231690/inner-shadow-in-uilabel) Long code but it seems to work