# How to create font as an image below?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fonts

How to create font as an image below?
[image]

This is "pressed" font.

Comment: You don't create fonts in code, http://ilovetypography.com/2007/10/22/so-you-want-to-create-a-font-part-1/

Comment: Elvis Nunez - how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that effect with Core Graphics, making an inner shadow in your label, look here for the answer: [Inner Shadow in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231690/inner-shadow-in-uilabel)