# How to flip button in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to know how buttons are flipped in the following app:

http://itunes.apple.com/app/brain-cafe-geoquiz/id334815548?mt=8

I am refering to this screen in the app:

[image]

Comment: That looks more like an image which set when the button is in selected state. If thats the case its definitely possible

Comment: @7KV7, no, I am not refering to the shadow in button on selected state. If you check the app, these buttons are flipped everytime a new question appears. That is what I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the following code:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:button cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic inner shadows in CoreGraphics... see [Inner Shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169119/inner-shadow-in-core-graphics)

Comment: May I did not mention it correctly. What I am looking for is: a way to flip the buttons the way this app does.