# Adding effects on image in iPad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, image-processing

I am playing with images in my application and I wonder if it is possible to make something like inner shadow/drop shadow on my images in the application? The reason why I am asking is where/what should I start reading if I want something like that if it is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library called Core Graphics. Check this [article](http://www.wideasleep.com/blog/?p=199). Then of course, there is my favorite [information source](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss) apart from SO. Just for kicks, there is this [article](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000053.php) to be read, but since it was a private API (and I'm not sure it's still doable), it's only for reading pleasure.

By the way, have you looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169119/inner-shadow-in-core-graphics)? It's not exactly your problem, but does bring some information you might want to read.